# Convert .csv to .bed in linux

Tags: csv, awk

I want to convert a file with .csv format to .bed using "awk" command.
But I don't know how can I define space for this command..
Would you please guide me?

Comment: Better show how a .bed file looks like and -of course- some of your attempts. Currently this is too broad.

Comment: Are you just trying to replace commas with spaces or tabs?

Comment: Show  a sample of your input and your desired output (as well as what you've tried, assuming you have).  This seems like a very simply task but we do not have enough information to determine if any solution is doing what you want or not.

Comment: [bed format](https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat.html#format1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tr` to translate characters. I looked up .bed files, and it looks like they are just tab-delimited.

```
echo "1,2,3" | tr ',' '\t'
```

Prints out `1    2    3`, so running `cat file1.csv | tr ',' '\t' > file2.bed` should get you a tab-delimited file.

Comment: `tr ',' '\t' < file.csv > file.bed`